# Angular.Copy returning RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. How to resolve?

Tags: angularjs

Is there an upper bound on angular.copy?  I have a somewhat complex object that I would like to copy and I am getting the Max call stack error.

Comment: You have DOM elements in there? They have pointers all over the place (parent, children, etc) and end up referencing the entire document. They can't be copied that way.

Answer (score 4):

it's likely you have **circular references** inside your own object. Below is an example of a case:

```
var objectA = {};
var objectB = {};

//circular references
objectA.property = objectB; 
objectB.property = objectA;

$scope.object = {
  propertyA : objectA,
  propertyB: objectB
}
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/oidnlkMOVDvQ82zKwpQD?p=preview)

Comment: Haven't found it yet but I agree that this SHOULD be the issue.  Thanks.

Comment: @Eric G: Good luck for you. Hope you find out the issue soon.

Comment: I've seen this error before and have solved the issue using jQuery.extend(true, {}, obj) instead.

Comment: jq extend fixed for me as well, perhaps its a bug in older versions of angular.copy?